# Dropdown selection for smaller screens

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I'm creating a mobile first website. As the screen size gets smaller i want the selection buttons, drop downs, date pickers etc. to appear as a scrollable popup list in the browser. [I want the regular drop down button options to be displayed like this as the screensize gets smaller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68IAz.jpg)

How do I accomplish this? Is it a built in feature?

Comment: That's just how Mobile Safari displays the options for a select field. Different browsers/devices display these differently and you'd be best to leave them to it because the device user will be used to different display types.

Answer (score 0):

What you looking for is the default browser behavior.

Small overview:

https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12155/is-it-good-to-leave-select-dropdown-with-default-style-for-better-ux-and-accessi